# TZipFile read UTF8

Tags: c++, utf-8, c++builder, zip

I am trying to extract a (UTF-8) text file from a zip file:

```
TZipFile *zFile = new TZipFile;
zFile->Open(L"C:\\test.zip", zmRead);

TByteDynArray bda;
zFile->Read(L"test.txt", bda);
zFile->Close();

ShowMessage(WideStringOf(bda));
```

This doesn't work. I get a string, but with weird content.

If I use `zFile->Extract()` it works fine, but I don't want to use the disk (performance).

Is there a way to use the read function on a UTF-8 file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `TZipFile` itself, the real problem is actually with `WideStringOf()` instead.

`TZipFile::Read()` returns the *raw* bytes of the specified archived file (decompressing if needed), so your `bda` variable is a UTF-8 encoded byte array.  However, `WideStringOf()` expects a byte array that is encoded as UTF-16LE instead.  That is why you are seeing incorrect results.

To decode the byte array as UTF-8, use this instead:

```
ShowMessage(TEncoding::UTF8->GetString(bda));
```